# Not able to load css files in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

When I hit my angular application url it loads all the css and works as it should. However, when click any link to route to different links I am not able to css files. Below is my code.

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('app')
    .config(["$routeProvider", "$translateProvider",
        function($routeProvider, $translateProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'src/login/login.html',
                    controller: 'LoginController',
                    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
                }).
                when('/home', {
                    templateUrl: 'src/login/home.html',
                    controller: 'RegistrationController',
                    controllerAs: 'regCtrl'
                }).


                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
            $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader( {
                "prefix": "src/locale/", "suffix": ".json"
            } );

            $translateProvider.preferredLanguage( "en" );
        }])
```

Comment: The css files are same for whole application.

Comment: I can't understand your question: when you click a link, you're staying in the angular application, on the same page, where the CSS files have already been loaded, right. So, how could the CSS files not be loaded. Please elaborate, show the code. Tell which link you click, what is suppposed to happen, and what happens precisely.

Answer (score 1):

Batter to write a service to add CSS and JS files to the

Here is a example..

```
https://github.com/Yappli/angular-css-injector
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, let me go through it.